# MYSQL Query issue and subquery

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I'm trying to get everything from product_description and a description from order_product.

Thing is that when I have no result in order_product I just don't get any results.
(Even if there is something in product_description)

I probably need a sub query, but i can't figure out how to do it.

Any idea would be appreciated

```
SELECT *
FROM
  " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description
  INNER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product ON (" . DB_PREFIX . "product_description.product_id = " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product.product_id)
WHERE
  order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'
AND " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description.language_id = 2")
```

Comment: if you want all results from left table, use left join.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how `INNER JOIN` works. Inner join compares every row in table A to every row in table B and only returns rows that match the filter criteria.

If you do not have any rows in order_product, then your match will fail and inner join will return nothing.

What you want is `OUTER JOIN`. Specifically, you want a `LEFT JOIN`

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product ON (" . DB_PREFIX . "product_description.product_id = " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product.product_id)
WHERE
  order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'
AND " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description.language_id = 2")
```

What will happen now is you'll get all rows from product_description matching order_id = $order_id. If there is no row in order_product that matchs product_id, then the fields from order_product will be `NULL`

Also, I'd use aliases to clean up your query. You can name a table using `AS`  to create short cuts, and you should only select the columns you actually want (as you said in your description

```
SELECT pd.*, op.description
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description AS pd
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product as op
    ON (pd.product_id = op.product_id)
WHERE
    pd.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'
    AND pd.language_id = 2
```

Also, be very careful about interpolating variables into queries like you are with $order_id. If this is user submitted data, you could be in for some nasty surprises.

I would research prepared statements using whatever language and SQL Library you're using to deal with this. I'd provide examples, but i dont know what language or API you're using.